# new window onload never trigger in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open, document.write

I have a html page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var my= window.open();
    my.document.write('<body>salam</body>');
   }
  </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

when I click on the button , new page is open but loading not finish, what is the problem with code? I want to do somthing when my.onload trigger but never complete.

Comment: what is mean by `loading not finish`

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: my.onload not trigger and loading circle in the opened tab spins  replace the code in this page :https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

Comment: i tried it its working fine and network was also stopped after 3 sec.

Comment: You don't have any `onload` event defined

Comment: window.open(). opens new window and document.write(). writes new thing in window if you want salam in existing window use this "document.write('<body>salam</body>');" if you want to open window with salam then write new html and open it. What exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an open document. The loading indicator on the tab will remain active while it is open. Simply [close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/close) the document when done writing:

```
function myFunction() {
  var my= window.open();
  my.document.write('<body>salam</body>');
  my.document.close();
}
```

As for your `onload` not working you don't show having one defined. If you have one in your actual code it wouldn't have run since your document was still "loading".  Otherwise if you didn't have one you would obviously need to add it:

```
function myFunction() {
  var my= window.open();
  my.document.write(`<body onload="console.log('loaded')">salam</body>`);
  my.document.close();
}
```